# outlook shared mailbox contacts in a excel list with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm looking for a vba code in excel, he should contacts from a shared mailbox (different exchange account called shared mailbox in outlook) transfer to a excel list, with the normal contacts from outlook it works I used this:

```
Set nsOutlook = applOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

`Set cfOutlook = nsOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)`

with `Set olcontacts = cfOutlook.Folders("name")`

I have used the "name" where is displayed in outlook
it not works he not find the folder.

is there a solution without recipient?
because there will be several user-all with the same shared mailbox

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class which returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example:

```
Sub ResolveName()  
  Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
  Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder  

  Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
  Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Dan Wilson")  
  myRecipient.Resolve  

  If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
    Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
  End If  
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
  CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, if I use the GetSharedDefaultFolder method it works but only the normal contacts are moved to excel, not the shared mail box contacts, the shared mailbox is accessed via exchange cache mode.